# How to keep value of select after two posts?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have one selectbox and one set of radiobuttons on my website. I want to keep the value of the selectbox after I've changed radiobutton. I've managed to keep the value in the selectbox but when I press the other radiobutton I get this error

"Notice: Undefined index: checkGame on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: checkGame on line 13"

Here's my code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['checkGame'] != 'Any')
    {
        $game = $_POST['checkGame'];
        $sql="SELECT ipaddress, port FROM servers WHERE game=('$game')";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($serverConnectionArray, ["address" =>$row['ipaddress'], "port" =>$row['port']]);
    }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['playersSort']))
    {
        if($_POST['playersSort'] == 'Players Descending')
        {
              uasort($serverArray, function($a, $b) {
                return $b['Players'] <=> $a['Players'];
                });  
        }
        if($_POST['playersSort'] == 'Players Ascending')
        {
              uasort($serverArray, function($a, $b) {
                return $a['Players'] <=> $b['Players'];
                });  
        }
        if($_POST['playersSort'] == 'Max Players Descending')
        {
              uasort($serverArray, function($a, $b) {
                return $b['MaxPlayers'] <=> $a['MaxPlayers'];
                });  
        }
                    if($_POST['playersSort'] == 'Max Players Ascending')
        {
              uasort($serverArray, function($a, $b) {
                return $a['MaxPlayers'] <=> $b['MaxPlayers'];
                });  
        }
    }

    <form method="post">
    Game:
    <select name="checkGame">
        <option value="Any"<?php if (isset($game) && $game=="Any") echo "selected";?>>Any</option>
        <option value="Garrys Mod"<?php if (isset($game) && $game=="Garrys Mod") echo "selected";?>>Garrys Mod</option>
        <option value="Counter Strike Global Offensive"<?php if (isset($game) && $game=="Counter Strike Global Offensive") echo "selected";?>>Counter Strike Global Offensive</option>
        <option value="Counter Strike Source"<?php if (isset($game) && $game=="Counter Strike Source") echo "selected";?>>Counter Strike Source</option>
        <option value="Team Fortress 2"<?php if (isset($game) && $game=="Team Fortress 2") echo "selected";?>>Team Fortress 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter"/>
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="playersSort" value="Players Descending">Players Descending
        <input type="radio" name="playersSort" value="Players Ascending">Players Ascending
        <input type="radio" name="playersSort" value="Max Players Descending">Max Players Descending
        <input type="radio" name="playersSort" value="Max Players Ascending">Max Players Ascending
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sort" />
    </form>
```

Comment: The 2nd form doesn't appear to affect anything - or at least you have not shared the code that is processed when that form is submitted. You could, I would have thought, have just the one form! Also the sql is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: I've added the code for the 2nd form. The reason for the two forms was that I wanted to have the code on different locations, thinking about it now again. I can probably still have that even with one form... Thanks! What can I do to fix the vulnerability?

Comment: Yeah everything worked when I just used one form. I've been retarded. Shouldn't code at 3 am lol. Cheers! I would still love to hear about the vulnerability though.

Comment: The sql has an embedded variable - the variable being a POST parameter ( thus user supplied & untrustworthy ) called `checkGame` - to avoid sql injection you ought to use `prepared statements` which should be straightforward enough as you are already using `mysqli` Also - you are running the query twice ( `$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);` )

Comment: The 2nd piece of POST processing ( `if(isset($_POST['playersSort'])){......}` ) references an array `$serverArray` - where does this come from? It looks like it might be `$serverConnectionArray` but they are in different scopes so .... where is it defined?

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try to fix it. $serverArray comes from this             array_push($serverArray, ["HostName" =>$data['HostName'], "Players" =>$data['Players'], "MaxPlayers" =>$data['MaxPlayers'], "Map" =>$data['Map'],"ModDesc" =>$data['ModDesc'], "Ip" =>$server_address, "Port" =>$server_port]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the code for a while and mentioning the need to prevent sql injection I then spent an hour or so cobbling the following together - initially the code was just to show how you might use a `prepared statement` but eventually became what you see below. None of this is tested so there might be syntax errors here and there - they will become obvious I suspect.

There seemed no point to my mind of having two forms - so they have been combined here and the `sort` radio buttons have a hidden field with a value of zero - the idea here is that if no radio button is selected then there will always be a value of zero submitted - which is useful when processing the POST array.

The names of each game are defined in an array before any processing is done - which allows POSTed values to be checked they are valid and also allows the `SELECT` menu options and `RADIO`buttons to be generated dynamically - which, when combined with the `SESSION` variables ( `'game' & 'sort'`), allows the original goal of remembering previously submitted values regardless of which button is pressed.

```
<?php

    session_start();



    /*
        include database connection script or define here
    */

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );




    if( !isset( $_SESSION['game'] ) )$_SESSION['game']=false;
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['sort'] ) )$_SESSION['sort']=false;


    $games=array(
        'Any',
        'Garrys Mod',
        'Counter Strike Global Offensive',
        'Counter Strike Source',
        'Team Fortress 2'
    );
    $sorts=array(
        0,
        'Players Descending',
        'Players Ascending',
        'Max Players Descending',
        'Max Players Ascending'
    );

    $svrconn=array();



    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){


        if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['checkGame'], $_POST['playersSort'] ) && $_POST['checkGame'] != 'Any' ){
            try{

                $game = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'checkGame', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
                if( !in_array( $game, $games ) ) throw new Exception('Unknown game');

                $_SESSION['game']=$game;

                /* create the sql statement with a placeholder `?` */
                $sql  = 'select `ipaddress`, `port` from `servers` where `game`=?';

                /* Attempt to create the `prepared statement` */
                $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

                /* statement was successfully created */
                if( $stmt ){

                    /* bind a variable to the placeholder & execute query */
                    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $game );
                    $result=$stmt->execute();

                    /* Yay! There are results to process */
                    if( $result ){

                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $stmt->bind_result( $ip, $port );

                        while( $rs=$stmt->fetch() ){
                            $svrconn[]=array( 'address'=>$ip, 'port'=>$port );
                        }

                        $stmt->free_result();
                        $stmt->close();
                        $db->close();

                    } else {/* bogus - no results */
                        throw new Exception('No results');
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('sql query failed to prepare');
                }
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                exit( $e->getMessage() );
            }
        }

        /*
            Because of the hidden field with a value of `0` this will not be invoked
            unless a radio button is selected.
        */
        if( !empty( $_POST['playersSort'] ) ){
            try{

                $sort=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'playersSort', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
                if( !in_array( $sort, $sorts ) ) throw new Exception('Unknown sort');
                $_SESSION['sort']=$sort;


                /*

                    presumably the array ( $svrconn ~ originally $serverConnectionArray or $serverArray? )
                    is used elsewhere in the page to display content???


                    apply filter/sorting algorithms 
                */
                switch( strtolower( $sort ) ){
                    case 'players descending':
                        uasort( $svrconn, function($a,$b) {
                            return $b['Players'] <=> $a['Players'];

                        }); 
                    break;
                    case 'players ascending':
                        uasort( $svrconn, function($a,$b) {
                            return $a['Players'] <=> $b['Players'];
                        });
                    break;
                    case 'max players descending':
                        uasort( $svrconn, function($a,$b) {
                            return $b['MaxPlayers'] <=> $a['MaxPlayers'];
                        });
                    break;
                    case 'max players ascending':
                        uasort( $svrconn, function($a,$b) {
                            return $a['MaxPlayers'] <=> $b['MaxPlayers'];
                        });
                    break;
                }
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                exit( $e->getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Games n stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <fieldset>
                Game:
                <select name='checkGame'>
                <?php

                    $html=array();
                    foreach( $games as $value ){
                        $selected=trim( strtolower( $_SESSION['game'] ) )==trim( strtolower( $value ) ) ? 'selected=true' : '';
                        $html[]="<option value='$value' $selected>$value";
                    }
                    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
                ?>
                </select>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Filter' />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <?php

                    $html=array();
                    foreach( $sorts as $value ){
                        $checked=( trim( strtolower( $_SESSION['sort'] ) )==trim( strtolower( $value ) ) ) ? 'checked' : '';

                        /* 
                            having a hidden field means `playersSort` 
                            will always be present in POSTed data 
                            ( unless someone is deliberately hijacking the form ) 
                        */
                        if( empty( $value ) )$html[]="<input type='hidden' name='playersSort' value='$value' />";
                        else $html[]="<input type='radio' name='playersSort' value='$value' $checked>$value";
                    }
                    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
                ?>

                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sort' />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your time and effort. I will improve my code around this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
<input type="submitSort" name="submit" value="Sort" />
```

You are setting your submit button to a type of `submitSort` when it should be `submit`

You can change the name of the submit using the `name` field but the type needs to be `submit` to work like a submit button should

I would also advise using `$_SESSION` varibles to store things after post

Here is a quick example:

*It might not be the best way to do it, its to show the concept (please edit with any amends)*

```html
    $_SESSION['game'] = "";
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['checkGame'] != 'Any')
    {
        $_SESSION['game'] = $_POST['checkGame'];
    }

    if ($_SESSION['game'] == "1") { $gameCOD = "selected"; } else $gameCOD = "";
    if ($_SESSION['game'] == "2") { $gameBAT = "selected"; } else $gameBAT = "";
    
    <form method="post">
    <select name="checkGame">
        <option value="1">Any</option>
        <option value="2" <?php echo $gameCOD; ?> > COD </option>
        <option value="3" <?php echo $gameBAT; ?> > BATTLEFIELD </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Oh okay. Does it have to be the same as the first one? I've tried that but it breaks my site when I press it then. I get "
Notice: Undefined index: checkGame in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Source-Query-master\Examples\list.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: checkGame in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Source-Query-master\Examples\list.php on line 13" I  will update my post with more code. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm its hard to tell because your code is a little confusing :)

Comment: Haha okey :D Just started with php so It's probably horrible.

Comment: No you're doing well if you have only just started! But yeah, look into AJAX too. It will look complicated but once you find an example that works it will save your life :) It basically submits form without refreshing the page. Its already built into JQuery too so no need for additional addons :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to play around with this and understand it.